# need matched 2 string and remain html output string

Tags: php, string

need matched 2 string and add < p > tag after matched string, for example;

```
$string1="<p>he adventures <p>
<p>of < span >adolescence< /span > had taught Piet < span >Barol< /span > that he</p>";


$matching_with_string="he adventures
of adolescence had
taught Piet Barol 
that he";
```

i need string 1 output will be remain same with all include of HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
<?php
$strWithHTML="<p>he adventures <p>
<p>of < span >adolescence< /span > had taught Piet < span >Barol< /span > that he</p>";

$strWITHOUTHTML=str_replace(array('< ','/',' >','span'),'',strip_tags($string1));
```

**EDIT :**

> i wanna result will me HTML format

```
<?php
$strWithHTML="<p>he adventures <p>
<p>of < span >adolescence< /span > had taught Piet < span >Barol< /span > that he</p>";

echo htmlentities($strWithHTML);
```

Comment: if i removed tags for compare then how i result back all tags for output string?

Comment: You have two strings, `HTML formatted` and `Non-HTML` one

Comment: i wanna result will me HTML format